# Problems with UIScrollView when changing orientation , iOS

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, orientation, screen-orientation

I have an `UIScrollView` , where i show various settings for my application.

I created the `UIScrollView` from the builder , i added it as a sub view to my View and from the size inspector of the builder i placed it in position Y: -10 , to show just under my navigation bar. In my code i just added

```
self.scrollView.contentSize =CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width,1000);
```

and everything works as expected.

My problem starts , when i try to rotate the screen. Two major problems arise.

The **first** one is that , the start of the UIScrollView is not the same. It "starts" from a lower place than it should , hiding some options. *(image below)*

The **second** one is that , the width of the UIScrollView is not automatically adjusted to the new screen orientation and is the same as before. *(image below)*

So what exactly should i do , to have a nice result on both orientations?

I attach images with both orientations. The first one is the portrait which "works" as expected , the second one is the landscape where the problems arise.

[image: Portrait mode]

[image: Landscape mode]

Comment: minimum iOS version for your app?

Comment: minimum iOS version is 4.3

Comment: Based on your layout, I'd prefer using a `UITableView` instead of a scrollview, which will be better for memory because of cell reuse. `UITableView` handles all the issues you're having automatically for you, as well. Just a thought.

Comment: its a really complicated menu with maps buttons etc etc and much work has been already done on it to make it work so i ll stick with it. any ideas what to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust your `scrollView` s `frame` in `-viewDidLayoutSubviews` (called when device rotates) or use [Springs and Struts](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IPhone_Rotation,_View_Resizing_and_Layout_Handling)

Comment: i really wanted to help. I suggested two possible options to solve your problem and googled for you to put a link to an even more helpful tutorial inside, so what is the problem? I would go with Springs & Struts btw. ( on your UIScrollView ) . Just google it if you don't like the tutorial I suggested and think to be helpful !

Comment: try something like this and if you don't like the behaviour, just change the springs/struts http://tinypic.com/r/2m4si3c/6